# PowerShell: ByValue vs ByPropertyName?

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can simplify an explanation.

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the difference between "ByValue" vs "ByPropertyName" in terms of pipeline parameter binding and how it works.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about what specifically is confusing you?  There is some good coverage on various MS and other blog posts that can be found with search https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+by+value+and+by+property+name   So it would be helpful if you gave some examples of what you are confused about.  Or even some code that is giving you results that is confusing you.   It wouldn't make much sense for us to just repeat what can be easily found.

Comment: The difference between `ValueFromPipeline` and `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` are documented in the help topic `about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`. Type in `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`, read the appropriate sections, and see if that answers your question(s).

Comment: When I have a moment I will reword my question with more detail. The problem is that in doing so I usually end up confusing myself all over again.